# How to read file only number of columns instead of line separator?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Basically my input file is processed from Abinitio DML file. But I want to read that file using Pyspark. In Abinitio they are divided lines using number of columns. Even though line separator '\n' they are using but inside the data also '\n' character is there. So I can't read the data with only line separator.

Sample.dat

`John\uFFFDN\uFFFD\x01\x01\x94\n\x01\uFFFD1234\uFFFDXYZ
Jole\uFFFDY\uFFFD\n\x01\uFFFD5678\uFFFDXYZ
Mercy\uFFFDN\uFFFD\x01\n\x94\uFFFD9765\uFFFD\n`

This is sample file with column separator is ('\uFFFD' or '\307' or '\xc7') separator. All the three separator represent same unicode value only.

In that inside data also '\n' character available. My File size is also more than 1GB. I tried some way but can't able to separate. Need some better solution.

```py
### My First Try: ####
line_separator = "\n"
column_separator = u"\ufffd"

conf={'textinputformat.record.delimiter':line_separator,'encoding':'iso-8859-1'}

rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile('file://home/user/Sample.dat', "org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat", "org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable", "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text", conf=conf).map(lambda l:l[1])

rdd_kohls=rdd.map(lambda line: line.split(column_separator) )

rdd_kohls.count()

### Second Try: ####
df = spark.sparkContext.binaryFiles('file://home/user/Sample.dat', 10)

rdd = df.map(lambda x: x[1]).flatMap(lambda s: s.split(line_separator))

rdd_kohls = rdd.map(lambda s: s.split(column_separator))

rdd_kohls.count()
```

Expected Result:

`Col1    Col1   Col2                 Col3   Col4
John    N      \x01\x01\x94\n\x01   1234   XYZ
Jole    Y      \n\x01               5678   XYZ
Mercy   N      \x01\n\x94           9765   \n`

Comment: Create an external table using `regex serde` by providing the pattern which then can be accessed with spark easily.

Answer (score 0):

This is some what help full..

https://www.ae.be/blog-en/ingesting-data-spark-using-custom-hadoop-fileinputformat/